# Display first letter only for glyph fonts (accessible way)

Tags: css, accessibility

I have a glyph font and want to use it to achieve this effect:

[image: Image of a custom twitter icon]

My code so far:

```
<div class="ico linkedin">linkedin</div>
        
.ico {border-radius:10em; background:black; color:white}
.linkedin {visibility:hidden;}
.linkedin:first-letter {
    font-family:'JustVector'; 
    font-size:900%; 
    text-indent:1em; 
    visibility:visible
 }
```

This does the trick in Chrome, but not in Firefox or Internet Explorer 9. Also, this isn't accessible, because JAWS doesn't read the `hidden` or `display:none` elements.

So, I tried something like:

```
.linkedin {position:absolute; left:-5em}
.linkedin:first-letter {/*etc*/ position:absolute; left:6em}
```

But it doesn't work. Is there a proper and **accessible** way to achieve this?

Comment: Most font-icons use the :before pseudoclass, not :first-letter. Maybe that's what's fouling up on FF and IE.

With regard to the text, why not make it opacity: 0 and make the div overflow: hidden?

Comment: `display:none` is not an element, they are technically rules, the none is an attribue. Hence the _valid_ change.

Comment: @RyanB Sorry, the phrase is intended to use that forms as adjectives... something like "that box, the `display:none` one". Perhaps in english grammar doesn't work that way (in spanish it does). Please, feel free to edit the question for its better understanding ;) But mind that JAWS reads the content itself (not the css rules nor attributes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, they present me a few questions about how to deal with this.

Well, finally I go with the easy one. I think it's accesible and more semantic, also works if there's no CSS in the page, also it's possible to be printed.

I have separated the first letter (the icon) with a margin of surrounding text, and I left the layer with `overflow:hidden;`. Then, have adjusted `margin` and `line-height`, to focus well the character/icon inside the circle.

The final code:

```
.ico {background:black; border-radius:10em; height:5em; overflow:hidden; position:relative; width:5em; color:white;}
.linkedin:first-letter {font-family:'JustVector'; font-size:400%; line-height: 1.3em; margin-left:0.2em; margin-right:1em;}
```

With that solution, screenreaders reads "linkedin" and it only display the icon for other users giving them enough information.

Answer (score 2):

The accessible way to use icons is to use `img` elements with adequate `alt` attributes, e.g.

```
<img src=smiley.gif alt="Just joking!">
```

Icon fonts (which is what you probably mean by “gliph font”) have inherent accessibility problems. Using e.g. letters and trying to fool browsers into rendering them as icons with CSS means that with CSS turned off, there are just the letters, which are wrong information. Using elements with empty content and CSS-generated content suffers from the same problem, except that instead of wrong information, there is no information, when CSS (or at least the visual part of CSS) is off.

Comment: If you use the :before selector to add the letter as content, it stops you getting random letters when CSS is disabled.  Using `aria-hidden="true"` prevents the letter from being read out by a screen reader. I would also argue that an icon is NOT content and should not be represented with `img`.  It's a background image at best

Comment: No content isn’t much better than random content. Using `aria-hidden` may help in a few situations, but it is ignored in normal browsing. Icons that have a message or function are content. An icon used just for decoration isn’t really an icon, but if you wish to use it, you can use either an `img` with `alt=""` or a background image; a practical criterion here is: do you want it to be included when the page is printed? (Background images are normally dropped in printing.)

Comment: I understand your premise, but in this case I prefer to avoid the use of images. Icons are displayed in different colors in different places and in different sizes. It is much simpler, and lighter for the page, use text icons I can change at will, besides, the advantage that they do not lose resolution on different devices. This answer is good, but in this situation I tend to try with generated content.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a truly accessible way of using icon fonts currently.  I know it's a bit span-tastic but this what my approach to this would be.

Firstly wrap the text in a span so we can hide it. And add another span for the icon

```
<div class="ico">
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="linkedin"></span>
    <span class="hide">linkedin</span>
</div>
```

Notice I've added `aria-hidden="true"` to my icon span.  This is to prevent the letter (used to render the icon) from being read out by the screen reader.

Now you can safely hide the text so it is accessible by screen readers and apply your icon using the `before` selector.

```
.linkedin:before {
    font-family: 'JustVector'; 
    content: 'l';
}

.hide{
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}
```

Comment: Extra code... mmmhhh... thanks for the info for the aria tag, it's pretty useful, but I think this isn't very semantic. Also, this will be a very good solution if the letter were a random one (in my case it matches with the first letter of the word, L paints linkedin logo, so, there isn't need to generate random content).